# How to read attributes of tag under another tag in xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I want to read value of suppose subTag1's name and id, currently I am able to read attributes of TAG1 but not able to read attributes of subTag1. i am using the following code:

```
  <TAG1>
<name ='tag1',id='ad'>
<subTAG1>
<name ='abc',id='123'>
<name ='asdfbc',id='143'>
</subTag1>
</TAG1>



    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: dataset,// url from where I am reading xml
                    dataType: "xml",
                    async: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    headers: {
                    },
                    success: function (xml) {

                              $(xml).find('TAG1').each(function () {
                                  var dsid = $(this).attr('id');
                                  var dsname = $(this).attr('name');
                              console.log("Dataset id ="+dsid);
                                  console.log("Dataset name ="+dsname);


                        });
```

Comment: `</subTag1>` shoudl be `</subTAG1>` and what are you doing with the commas? Generally your XML isn't XML. Take a look at [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp

Comment: yeah that is just for reference purpose I am using same tag </subTAG1>

Comment: This is just for reference , I have the complete working code i.e means able to read attributes of 1st tag but not the subtag

Comment: Use a find for 'TAG1' and inside add another find for 'subTAG1'

Comment: valid XML would look like this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TAG1 name='tag1' id='ad'>
<subTAG1 name='abc' id='123' />
<subTAG1 name='asdfbc' id='143' />
</TAG1>`

Comment: @Amegon I have tried the same but it didnt worked:  <br>        
                          $(xml).find('TAG1').each(function () {
                              $(xml).find('subTAG1').each(function () {
                                  var dsid = $(this).attr('id');
                                  var dsname = $(this).attr('name');
                                  console.log("Org ="+dsid);
                                  console.log("Org name ="+dsname);
                              });



                    });

Comment: @Marshmellow i am not used to ajax, but i guess (xml) is your root node, so instead try the second one like $(this).find('subTAG1'). To search from any element found for subelements. You need to have an object to the first tag to search for the second tag

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not valid:

- Any attribute shall have a name (the equal is not accepted like that)
- There are no comas between attributes
- Name of opening/closing tags shall match (and it is case-sensitive)
- All tags must be closed, either like <a></a> or like <a/>

So the resolved xml should be like:

```
<TAG1>
    <name value='tag1' id='ad'/>
    <subTAG1>
        <name value='abc' id='123'/>
        <name value='asdfbc' id='143'/>
    </subTAG1>
</TAG1>
```

In your JavaScript+JQuery code, the TAG1 element has no attribute, you should look for a "name" tag to get attributes:

```
success: 
    function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('name').each(
            function () {
               var dsid = $(this).attr('id');
               var dsname = $(this).attr('name');
               console.log("Dataset id ="+dsid);
               console.log("Dataset name ="+dsname);
            });
    }
```